# Scheduled Python Script to run on AWS that has high memory use

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have this python script that needs to be scheduled to run once a day. It will take around 4-6GB of memory (due to large amount of dataframe operations). I will be using AWS and I would like to what is the best practice to handle such task. Is it a good idea to put it in a container like docker before deployment?

Comment: That memory does it need to be on the RAM or is it more like a database that you access and get a portion of the data from?

Comment: it needs to be on ram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your memory needs to be on ram then I'd recommend using a [memory optimized ec2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/memory-optimized-instances.html) with a CloudWatch event.

To minimize the cost, however, you don't want to have this EC2 running the whole day so what you can do is have a couple of lambda functions sitting between CloudWatch and the EC2 to :

1. start the ec2 instance once the daily trigger runs and
2. stop the ec2 instance with a trigger from your Python code that runs once it's finished

If that doesn't make much sense let me know and I'll try and elaborate with a diagram.

Comment: interesting. i was wondering shouldn't it be more effective to create runner job using jenkins to start a slave ec2 instance when needed?

Comment: @sjishan that would work as well, but you'll be paying for the ec2 that contains Jenkins assuming that this instance needs to be on all the time.

Comment: great point. would it be possible for you to elaborate your solution with a diagram ? that will be very helpful. thanks.

Comment: @Naquib Ihab  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/
Found this in aws amazon website. I was wondering how to make lambda not just start the ec2 instance but also run a bunch of python script, or lets say run a bash script that runs a bunch  of python function.